# Pyside6/PyQT6: How can I change the font color on click?

Tags: pyqt, pyside, pyside6, pyqt6

I am a pyside6 learner. And I am trying to create a clock based on pyside6, and I'd like to change its font color on click. How can I make it work?

The following codes are parts of this project.

```py
class Clock(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.left = 1100
        self.top = 800
        self.width = 320
        self.height = 60

        # Menu
        self.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.mouseRightMenu)

        # Font
        self.font_color = 'blue'

        # UI
        self.initUI()

    def changeFontColor(self, fcolor) -> None:
        self.font_color = fcolor


   def mouseRightMenu(self, pos) -> None:
        self.menu = QMenu(self)

        # font color
        fontColorMenu = self.menu.addMenu('font color')
        self.actionB1 = QAction('black', self)
        self.actionB2 = QAction('red', self)
        self.actionB3 = QAction('yellow', self)
        self.actionB1.triggered.connect(self.changeFontColor('black'))

    def initUI(self) -> None:
        # geometry of main window
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        # label object
        self.label = QLabel()
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet(f'color:{self.font_color};')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    clock = Clock()
    clock.show()  # show all the widgets
    App.exit(App.exec())  # start the app
```

Currently `changeFontColor` function doesn't work, I don't know what I have miss here.

Comment: Replace `.connect(self.changeFontColor('black'))` by `.connect(lambda: self.changeFontColor('black'))`, otherwise you are not connecting the signal to a function (with pre-filled argument) but to a None.

Comment: @Guimoute that would still be insufficient, since `changeFontColor` only creates a new string as instance attribute, but will not alter the style sheet.

Comment: @musicamante You are right. I simply assumed that applying a stylesheet was trivial and addressing the signal/slot connection was more important and worth a comment, having struggled with it myself back when I started using Qt. Your answer covers everything so it's perfect!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing two fundamental aspects.

First of all `self.font_color` is just a variable (or, to be precise, an attribute).

You are *explicitly* using it within `initUi()` along with `self.label.setStyleSheet()`, but that doesn't "magically" make that variable interactive.

What you're doing would never work, and here's a basic explanation:

```py
color = 'blue'
styleSheet = f'color: {color}'
print(styleSheet)
color = 'green'
print(styleSheet)
```

If you consider the above, *both* the print statements will return the same value: changing `color` doesn't change `styleSheet`.

That is mostly due to the fact that strings are immutable types (so, `styleSheet` can *never* be affected by any change in `color`), but also because there's no dynamic relation between `color` and `styleSheet`.

What actually changes the aspect of a widget is an *explicit* call to `setStyleSheet()`, and changing the *string* contents used for a previous call is completely useless. You **must** call `setStyleSheet()` again in order to apply it.

Then, you're doing another mistake: signal connections use callables, but you're *explicitly* calling the `changeFontColor()` function.

Consider this:

```py
def myFunction(arg):
    print(f'arg is "{arg}"')
    return arg


# this is a call (note the parentheses), which will *execute* the function
>>> myFunction('hello')
# and will show the follwing:
arg is "hello"
# while the following will show a different result:
>>> print(myFunction('hello'))
arg is "hello"
hello

# this is a reference, which will do nothing
>>> myFunction
<function __main__.myFunction>
# notice tht difference with the above:
>>> print(myFunction)
<function myFunction at 0xZZZZZZZZ>
```

Using `self.someObject.someSignal.connect(someFunction())` is wrong, (**unless** `someFunction` returns a reference to another function).

You're directly calling your function (that doesn't return a callable), which actually prompts an error. You probably didn't notice (IDEs are often unable to show all output and full tracebacks, and most Qt errors are not fatal), but if you run your program in a terminal or prompt you'll probably see an error saying that a `TypeError` occurred, because you're trying to connect to a `NoneType`.

What you need to do is the following:

```py
    def changeFontColor(self, fcolor) -> None:
        # explicitly call setStyleSheet() with the color name
        self.label.setStyleSheet(f'color: {fcolor};')

    def mouseRightMenu(self, pos) -> None:
        # ...
        self.actionB1.triggered.connect(lambda: 
            self.changeFontColor('black'))
```

`lambda` creates a function reference, but doesn't call it: when the `triggered` signal is emitted, the function will finally be called.

The above is similar to the following:

```py
    def changeFontColor(self) -> None:
        self.label.setStyleSheet('color: black')

    def mouseRightMenu(self, pos) -> None:
        # ...
        self.actionB1.triggered.connect(self.changeFontColor)
```

With the difference that we directly call the function, which internally uses a static value (`'black'`).

I strongly suggest you to do some research on object references, callables, and object types.